# importing HoloEverywhere unable to find attribute divider

Tags: android, git, android-holo-everywhere, holoeverywhere

I imported HoloEverywhere using git and got so many errors but I managed to fix some of them. However, i can't find solution for this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:libs:HoloEverywhere:processReleaseResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    D:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\19.0.0\aapt.exe package -f --no-crunch -I D:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-19\android.jar -M D:\Users\Kelvz\AndroidStudioProjects\AUFMobileSchoolBliz\app\libs\HoloEverywhere\build\bundles\release\AndroidManifest.xml -S D:\Users\Kelvz\AndroidStudioProjects\AUFMobileSchoolBliz\app\libs\HoloEverywhere\build\res\all\release -A D:\Users\Kelvz\AndroidStudioProjects\AUFMobileSchoolBliz\app\libs\HoloEverywhere\build\bundles\release\assets -m -J D:\Users\Kelvz\AndroidStudioProjects\AUFMobileSchoolBliz\app\libs\HoloEverywhere\build\source\r\release --non-constant-id --output-text-symbols D:\Users\Kelvz\AndroidStudioProjects\AUFMobileSchoolBliz\app\libs\HoloEverywhere\build\bundles\release
Error Code:
    1
Output:
    ERROR: In <declare-styleable> LinearLayoutICS, unable to find attribute divider
```

This is my HoloEverywhere's build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
    }

    sourceSets {

        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
        }

    }
}


dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile files('libs/support-v4-19.1.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
}
```

This is my main application's build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':app:libs:HoloEverywhere')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Comment: Did you try the last build tools? `19.1` or at least `19.0.3`. I remember that there was an issue related with old build tool versions. Probably related to [#763](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere/issues/763)

Comment: Looks as though the problem in the "compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'". Are you sure that it is imported?

Comment: Did you manage to solve it? I have just felt into the same problem.